# Adding Disqus to wordpress effect SEO

Tags: seo, wordpress, search-engine-indexing

I am planning to add Disqus to my WordPress site. Now will my comments will be indexed by the Google as earlier or do I have to add any extra plugins or sitemap for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your comments on Disqus will be indexed in Google as explained [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-the-new-disqus-and-f-a-q-).

> The iframe is part of our solution to provide full indexing of Disqus
>   comments by Google and other search engines, without having to
>   duplicate content on your website (e.g., through a WordPress plugin).

The benefits of using Disqus as a comment plugin are questionable though...

Comment: Google doesn't index Disqus comments unless you print them on the html yourself.